# moment.js converting epoch date to specific timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I've been looking for days to find how to get moment.js to behave correctly and return the correct date for a specific local time zone.

Here is my challenge:

1. I'm calling a flight api to get the "arrival date/time" of a flight. It provides me the arrival time in epoch time and a timezone for the airport.
2. I'm using javascript moment.js to convert that to the local time of the airport, BUT, the time always comes in a couple days ahead.

Here's my code:
    var dateVal = 1395184260;
    var day = moment.unix(dateVal).tz('America/Vancouver').format();
    console.log("tz :",day);

// should return: 4:21 PM - Sun Mar-16-2014 BUT it always returns the 18th instead of the 16th.

Comment: Where is this code running, on a remote node server or in your browser?

Answer (score 4):

Where are you getting the "should return" from?

According to http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php?epoch=1395184260, your time should be

> Mar 18 2014 16:11:00 GMT-7:00

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimschubert/URZf4/) using your timestamp:

```
var dateVal = 1395184260;
var date = moment.unix(dateVal);
console.log(date.tz("America/Vancouver").format('ll HH:mm:ss Z'))
```

returns:

> Mar 18 2014 16:11:00 -07:00

I'd check whatever converter you're using to see if there's a bug.

Comment: I believe it's incorrect because according to this: http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?id=348588653&airline=WS&flightNumber=191&departureDate=2014-03-16 it shoes that my flight arrived at March 16th, not March 18, and the flight api is giving me that epoch time...

Comment: I'd check that you're evaluating the right response. Executing the following on linux command line `TZ="America/Vancouver" date -d @1395184260` results in `Tue Mar 18 16:11:00 PDT 2014`. This March 18 date for the given unix timestamp isn't the problem.